# Keeping the text the same color when selected in a css vertical flyout menu

Tags: html, css

I need your help.

How can the CSS markup below be modified such that the color white is present thoughout the users selection? As it is now, when a section has been hovered, the text remains blue except for the last part selected. Notice that the blue color is not white throughout the user's selection.

See a picture below:

[image]

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8"/>
<title></title>
<style type="text/css">
#navigation {
    width: 150px;
    font-size: 0.75em;
}
#navigation ul {
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
}

ul.top-level {
    background: rgb(238,238,238);
}

#navigation li {
    list-style: none;
}
ul.top-level li {
    border-bottom: #fff solid;
    border-top: #fff solid;
    border-width: 1px;
}

#navigation a {
    color: rgb(41,83,118);
    cursor: pointer;
    display:block;
    height:25px;
    line-height: 25px;
    text-indent: 10px;                  
    text-decoration:none;
    width:100%;
}
#navigation a:hover{ 
    text-decoration:underline;
        color: #fff;
}
#navigation li:hover {
    background: rgb(85,85,85);
    position: relative;
}

ul.sub-level {
    display: none;
}
li:hover .sub-level {
    border: #fff solid;
    border-width: 1px;
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    left: 150px;
    top: 0px;
}
ul.sub-level li {
    border: none;
    float:left;
    width:150px; 
}
#navigation .sub-level {
    background: rgb(238,238,238);
}
#navigation .sub-level .sub-level {
    background: rgb(238,238,238);
}

li:hover .sub-level .sub-level {
    display:none;
}

.sub-level li:hover .sub-level {
  display:block;
  position: absolute;
  left: 150px;
}

</style>
</head>
    <body>
        <div id="navigation">
            <ul class="top-level">
                <li><a href="#">Home</a>
                    <ul class="sub-level">
                        <li><a href="#">Sub Menu Item 1</a>
                </li>
                        <li>
                            <a href="#">Sub Menu Item 2</a>
                            <ul class="sub-level">
                                <li><a href="#">Sub Sub Menu Item 1</a></li>
                                <li><a href="#">Sub Sub Menu Item 2</a></li>
                                <li><a href="#">Sub Sub Menu Item 3</a></li>
                                <li><a href="#">Sub Sub Menu Item 4</a></li>
                            </ul>
                        </li>
                        <li><a href="#">Sub Menu Item 3</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Sub Menu Item 3</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
                <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">FAQ</a>
                    <ul class="sub-level">
                        <li><a href="#">Sub Menu Item 1</a></li>
                        <li>
                            <a href="#">Sub Menu Item 3</a>
                            <ul class="sub-level">
                                <li><a href="#">Sub Sub Menu Item 1</a></li>
                                <li><a href="#">Sub Sub Menu Item 2</a></li>
                                <li><a href="#">Sub Sub Menu Item 3</a></li>
                                <li><a href="#">Sub Sub Menu Item 4</a></li>
                            </ul>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="#">News</a>
                    <ul class="sub-level">
                        <li><a href="#">Sub Menu Item 1</a>
                            <ul class="sub-level">
                                <li><a href="#">Sub Sub Menu Item 1</a></li>
                                <li><a href="#">Sub Sub Menu Item 2</a></li>
                                <li><a href="#">Sub Sub Menu Item 3</a></li>
                                <li><a href="#">Sub Sub Menu Item 4</a></li>
                            </ul>
                        </li>
                        <li><a href="#">Sub Menu Item 2</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Sub Menu Item 3</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add the following at the end of your css: (**[Working jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/HW3Xm/1/)**)

```css
#navigation li:hover > a{ /* Thanks @ExplosionPills */
    color:white;
}
```

Comment: This turns the sublist menu items white too when yo uhover.  See my answer for an explanation and fix

Comment: I like it! It works. I will accept! I have alot of CSS stuff to learn. Most of it has been self-taught Youtube videos

Answer (score 2):

Change `#navigation a:hover` to `#navigation li:hover > a`.  The `<a>` is not parents of the sublist.  You will remain hovered over the list while hovered over the sublist.  The child selector (`>`) is necessary or else *all* `a` descendants will be white in the sublists which is undesirable.

http://jsfiddle.net/nvEza/

Comment: Out of curiosity, does IE7 support `:hover` on non-anchor elements?

Comment: @MrSlayer I believe so

Comment: Confirmed. IE7 does in standards mode. This is probably the better solution than wrapping the sub-menu with an anchor.

Answer (score 0):

I have seen it where the anchor wraps the entire sub-menu, like so:

```
<a href="#">
   News
   <ul class="sub-level">
      ...
   </ul>
</a>
```

This way, when you are hovering over a sub-menu, the parent anchor is still active, as well.

Answer (score -2):

Use the hover on the parent to set the child colors in that state.

```
#navigation .top-level:hover li a{color:#fff;}
```

Comment: This turns all menu items white when a list is hovered